# How to force Python garbage collection on a running script

Tags: python, garbage-collection

In order to investigate some issues with unreleased system resources I'd like to **force immediate garbage collection** on an **already running** python script.

Is this somehow possible, e.g. by sending some kind of signal that Python would understand as an order to run gc; or any other similar way? Thanks.

I'm running Python 2.7 on a Linux server.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Like an API to send a signal to the process and tell it to do something(gc)? And in what conditions do you want to execute it? Manually, cron, when certain event takes place, something else?

Comment: I'm looking for a manual command to execute against a particular Python process (namely uwsgi).

Comment: Well @TkTech already suggested the signal module. I could add RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ, though you'd have to, let's say, create a separate thread to listen for signals. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) is a very simple and straightforward. I personally like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) a whole lot more because of it's flexibility but it's a bit more difficult if you have no prior experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a signal handler using the built-in [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) module, then call [gc.collect()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) from your custom handler.

If you have no control over the application, you'll have to use something like [pyringe](https://github.com/google/pyringe), which will allow you to insert arbitrary python.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to a running python script with debugger and issue any command within it, like inside interactive console. I used PyCharm's debugger, but there are variety of them.